# Pipe program output to CSV file

Tags: bash, csv

I am currently programming benchmarks for my thesis.
Until now I copied the output of my program to a calc tool and generated the plots for it.

Now I would like to save some time and write a bash cript which will run my program 15 times and write the results in a CSV file.

Output looks like this

```
2.400376 
12.917778 
16.106343 
15.971737 
17.167294 
17.075996 
17.057590 
17.113480 
17.074406 
17.064394 

2.718820 
11.456631 
16.918703 
17.725768 
17.833584 
17.808625 
17.883213 
17.889387 
17.899784 
17.894960
```

The output of the following loop should be saved in the next column of the CSV

Any suggestions how to do this?
I have some basic knowlegde of bash scripting but this is beyond my possibilities currently

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put the values into the file by *row* instead by *column*, and then use a *spreadsheet* to pivot the values? *Much* easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your program 15 times:

```
for i in {1..15}; do
  myprogram >> ${i}.txt
done
```

Join all the outputs together in one file, specifying a comma as the delimiter:

```
paste -d ',' {1..15}.txt > output.csv
```

If you are not using `bash`, you could replace the `{1..15}` construct with `$(seq 1 15)`.